# mudança de elemento jquery com intervalo de tempo

Tags: jquery, funções, jquery-animate

Eu gostaria de fazer com que 3 ou mais blocos de animação que, ao clicar, ficasse mudando de acordo com os segundos, até que alguém clique em um dos objetos.

A função está funcionando para clique. 
Ao clicar ele alterna entre as classes.

Eu queria que ficasse rodando até ser clicado

```
        var toggleClasscontentflow = function() {
        $('div.prime').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('primeclicked');
```

> Troca

```
        });         
        $('div.second').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('secondclicked');
```

> troca

```
        });         
        $('div.third').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('thirdclicked');
```

> troca

```
        });};
    $(document).ready(toggleClasscontentflow);
```

Ou seja, fica trocando entre os três até que clique em um deles

Comment: pow, perguntinha ficou em branco mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito o seu problema, mas acho que isso pode te ajudar:

```
$(function(){
   var interval;

   $('div').on('click', function(){
       $('div').removeClass();
       clearInterval(interval);

       interval = setInterval(function(){
           $('div').removeClass()
           for(var i = 1; i<= 3; i++){
               var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
               $('#div-'+i).addClass('clicked-'+number);
           }
       }, 1000);
   });
});
```

Link para ver o código funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/yoz2t3aL/1/

Comment: Foi esse o motivo de desistir de responder essa pergunta: Não deu pra entender direito o que ele quer